# urllib2 read response more than once

Tags: python, urllib2

I am trying to modify SQLmap connect class (https://github.com/sqlmapproject/sqlmap/blob/master/lib/request/connect.py) to meet my needs.

What I want to do is to check if the response contains "CAUGHT BY WAF" and repeat that request until it doesn't contain it.

So after line 471 I added:

```
conn = urllib2.urlopen(req)
while('CAUGHT BY WAF' in conn.read()):
   conn = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

However this doesn't work because after doing `conn.read()`, SQLmap won't be able to read the response again as you can do it only once.

P.S: I tried to use deepcopy:

```
conn = urllib2.urlopen(req)
conn2 = copy.deepcopy(conn)
while('CAUGHT BY WAF' in conn2.read()):
   conn = urllib2.urlopen(req)
   conn2 = conn
```

but still doesn't work (no idea why!!)

So my question is: how can I do `conn.read()` more than once?

Thanks!

Comment: That is easy, assign `conn = urllib2.urlopen(req)` once more and you will be able to read again. But I don't think you really want to read again, you don't know if `'CAUGHT BY WAF'` will be there the next time you read.

Comment: The thing is I want SQLmap to be able to read the response that doesn't have 'CAUGHT BY WAF' but I don't want it to send the request again.

Comment: `deepcopy` won't work here because calling `read` on any of the copies will exhaust the same external resource. Basically you need a custom response object that won't read from the remote resource.

Answer (score 1):

The call is sending you a stream so if you want to use the data multiple times, you could save it in a temp file, and parse it from there.

```
content = conn.read()
file.write(content)
```